# Does a JavaScript variable not declared with var become global?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have the following code in one file:

```
function refreshGridSuccess(responseText, entity) {

    oTable = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "sScrollX": "100%",
```

In another file I have:

```
$('#detailData')
        .on('click', '.sort-up', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var column = $(this).closest('th'),
                columnIndex = column.parent().children().index(column.get(0));
            oTable.fnSort([[columnIndex, 'asc']]);
            return false;
        })
```

I have no definition for `oTable` except here. The scripts seem to work so does that mean that `oTable` was somehow made into a global variable?

Now I am trying to start using Typescript and it will not accept `Otable` without it being declared.  Is there a way I can declare `oTable` as an object or do I have to declare it as an object to be the same type as is returned by `$('#dataTable').dataTable({})` ?

Comment: To fix this, you need to explicitly put var oTable in your TypeScript. In your case, somewhere both usages can access.

Answer (score 3):

*If you're in the global scope then there's no difference.
If you're in a function then "var" will create a local variable, "no var" will look up the scope chain until it finds the variable or hits the global scope (at which point it will create it).*

Found here: [What is the purpose of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a variable not declared with var becomes global. When used outside of a function's scope it is not necessarily required, however, using a globally defined variable which was defined in a function results in unpredictable results.

"Failure to declare the variable in these cases will very likely lead to unexpected results. For that reason, in ECMAScript 5 strict mode, assigning a value an undeclared variable inside a function throws an error." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. Variable without a var declaration is treated as global. If you are in a browser, that scope is `window`

Also note that Javascript variables are function-scoped. Meaning if you have a code like this:

```
function test()
{
   for (var key in someObject)
   {
      var foo = 'bar';
   }
}
```

It is equivalent to this:

```
function test()
{
   var foo, key;
   for (key in someObject)
   {
      foo = 'bar';
   }
}
```

It doesn't matter which block the `var` declaration is placed in, the actual declaration happens at the beginning of the function. This is also called `variable hoisting` if you want to google it.

Now about `Typescript`, I haven't had a chance to play with it. But I assume you can still do `var oTable;` right before you use the variable?